# UWP app add an image (path) to SQLite Database

Tags: image, sqlite, uwp

Hi I am creating a UWP app and have the following method to upload a picture.

```
   async void imageButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FileOpenPicker open = new FileOpenPicker();
        open.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
        open.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;

        // Filter to include a sample subset of file types
        open.FileTypeFilter.Clear();
        open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".bmp");
        open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
        open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
        open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");

        // Open a stream for the selected file
        StorageFile file = await open.PickSingleFileAsync();

        // Ensure a file was selected
        if (file != null)
        {
            // Ensure the stream is disposed once the image is loaded
            using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
            {
                // Set the image source to the selected bitmap
                BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                bitmapImage.DecodePixelHeight = 200;
                bitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth = 200;

                await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(fileStream);
                image.Source = bitmapImage;
            }
        }
    }
```

I have a database created in SQLite and I would like to add the image path to the database but I have no idea how to code this with a UWP app. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you store the byte[] in a blob column of a SQLite table.
There is a good post about it available here http://andywigleyblog.azurewebsites.net/?p=117

It has the needed info to read and save the image.

Most import part is the conversion method

```
private byte[] ConvertToBytes(BitmapImage bitmapImage)
{
    byte[] data = null;
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        WriteableBitmap wBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(bitmapImage);
        wBitmap.SaveJpeg(stream, wBitmap.PixelWidth, wBitmap.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        data = stream.GetBuffer();
    }

    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For communication with SQLite could be used Entity Framework 7, and article, how to use it, could be found [here](http://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/uwp.html). But there is on problem, it just release candidate (EF 7.0.0-rc1) and has problems with compilation to .NET Native.