# Save image in SQLite (UWP)

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp

I followed some tutorial on YouTube and found how to install "SQLite for Universal Windows Platform", and I had to make one class with this in it:

```
[PrimaryKey,AutoIncrement]
public int ID { get; set; }
public string Content { get; set; }
```

It is for saving of a text. And in my `MainPage.xaml.cs` I made connection with this database like following

```
path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "db.sqlite");
conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(),path);
conn.CreateTable<Message>();
```

And then I added some text to it (when I click the button)

```
var add = conn.Insert(new Message() { Content = textBox.Text});
```

This all works fine, but how can I store image (which user will upload from their phone or Desktop) to this Database?

Comment: Have you checked this answer [Save and Load image SQLite C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853301/save-and-load-image-sqlite-c-sharp)?

Comment: This will maybe work but still I don't know how to save image to database ... @SergiiZhevzhyk

Comment: Probably, you should add more information and code concerning this problem. Show us what kind of images do you want to save.

Comment: I used FileOpenPicker to open let user select picture from phone or Desktop... After that I did this  `var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
                var image = new BitmapImage();
                image.SetSource(stream);
                imageXaml.Source = image;` And this just added selected image to `<Image Source...>`

Comment: was asked recently here too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34146359/uwp-app-add-an-image-path-to-sqlite-database/34150130#34150130 look at that maybe it will guide you more